# How to use Docusign - create envelope with Lightning

Tags: lightning, docusign

I need to open dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope from Lightning controller. I tried to use `e.force:navigateToURL` component:

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
   "url": "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID=" + cmp.get("v.recordId") +"&DST=" + dst + "&CRL=" + crl + "&CEM=" + cem,
   "isredirect": "true"
});
urlEvent.fire();
```

but I'm getting error `The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce administrator.`. I found a page with this error on docusign website https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-7-0-This-page-requires-a-CSRF-confirmation-token and it says to use `{!URLFOR}` for Docusing 7.0+, but as I understand it only works for Visualforce pages. How can I do it in lightning?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the URL from Apex using PageReference class and then return the URL to the Lightning Component controller.

Answer (score 0):

With CSRF being enabled on the Docusign managed package page (and I don't believe you can change it), there are three paths I've found to get around this:
1.  You can get the free Docusign Lightning component from the AppExchange.  This component (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFmotUAD) allows you to access Docusign from a Lightning page; not sure if a custom controller can call it.  Note there are limitations to this component (e.g., can't access from a custom object).
2.  Docusign prescribes a method to call it from a custom URL using the URLFOR() function.  This is well documented on their support pages (https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-7-0-This-page-requires-a-CSRF-confirmation-token).  Not sure what your use case is, but I was able to combine this guidance with a Visual Flow and some simple IF logic in a custom URL button to equate to what I'd had in the Classic-supported javascript button.
3.  It may be possible for your Lightning controller to call a VF page, which then calls Docusign. This was more intense than I needed, so I didn't explore this further.  In any event, I'm not a Salesforce security expert, but my sense is client side code (e.g., custom Lightning components) are prevented from accessing those VF pages with CSRF protection enabled (I confirmed this with a custom VF page, which threw the same error when the checkbox was enabled).